# How to navigate from UIButton to the next page in iphone OR How can i adjust push event against UIButton

Tags: iphone

I am a fresh student and just joined an iphone programming Software House as an internee. I am new in iphone programming but not in computer programming. I can't figure out how I can use a UIbutton to switch to the next viewcontroller.

My coding is as follows...

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (!self.detailViewController) {
        self.detailViewController = [[HelloDetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"HelloDetailViewController" bundle:nil];
    }
    NSDate *object = [_objects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    self.detailViewController.detailItem = object;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:self.detailViewController animated:YES];

}
```

Comment: Is the button inside the cell?

Answer (score 1):

Welcome abroad. Not so hard learn Objective-C programming. there's a lot tutorial on this though, you might want to familiar with all the `UINavitationController`, `UIViewController` as well as widgets (`UIButton` , `UILabel` etc).

so, to answer to your question, there's 2 ways doing it.

- create `IBAction` in `.h` then connect it to your button in xib.

`-(IBAction) submit;`

- let's say you have a button, call `IBOutlet UIButton *myButton`

> [myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(submit) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

your method:

```
-(void) submit{
 if (!self.detailViewController) {
        self.detailViewController = [[HelloDetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"HelloDetailViewController" bundle:nil];
    }
    //NSDate *object = [_objects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    //self.detailViewController.detailItem = object;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:self.detailViewController animated:YES];

}
```

Comment: where you're getting `indexPath.row`?

Comment: This will not compile unless he has an object `indexPath` as ivar that at each tap on the cell is updated.

Comment: aah, yeah, didn't see the parameter that passes there. i've edited my answer

Comment: Again, probably not good even in this way because if he wants to set `NSDate * object = [_objects objectAtIndex: indexPath.row];` must access the index of the datasource to get the value. He should detail the question to understand better :)

Comment: yeah, i don't get also why need to navigate away from button, since table could do it better the way it is.

Answer (score 0):

to simply switch to next viewcontroller write the following code

```
viewcontrollerobject=[[ViewControllerName alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewControllerXibName" bundle:nil];
[self.view addSubview:viewcontrollerobject.view];
```

if you need a navigation push view controller animation then use the code

```
 [self.navigationController pushViewController:ViewControllerName animated:YES];
```

This will take you simply to the next page....